# Android- Videos from assets folder will transfer into external storage

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, assets

Wondering if this idea exists. I want to transfer my video file from my asset folder into external storage and from there, the application will just call the video and use it for my android application. Is this possible? Can anyone guide me or give me an advice for what is the better thing to do. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want do do with it in your android app? And what is 'calling a video' ?

Comment: I will use the video for my app. Just for viewing purpose. Is this possible?

Comment: If your app can play video files it will be able to play your video file from external memory too. Why not? Unclear which problems you see.

Comment: The video that I want to use is from the SD Card separate from the app itself.

Comment: ?????? Now you made it totally unclear. And you did not react on my remarks.

Comment: Sir I want to access the video clip from the SD card using application.persistentdatapath. For now I am manually adding (COPY-PASTE) the video clip into Android/data/file/xx.xx.xx/ and the app is just calling the video clip from that path, which I think is wrong.

Comment: Why would that be wrong? The path is irrelevant i think.